# Dequeue notification table in Oracle

Tags: oracle, queue, notifications

I have implemented below sample. It is working fine. I am planning to integrate with this .net application. As soon i read the entry i would like to dequeue the entry. Can any one tell how i can achive that.

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/dbms_change_notification_10gR2.php

Meanwhile i am trying AQ. But it does not have good .net (C#)support

Comment: It's unclear - what do you mean by "entry" and from which queue you want to dequeue?

Latest version of ODP.NET supports AQ.